# Is it possible to start an application without a window manager?

Tags: games, window-manager, window, session

I have some really old machines that I want to run some games on. I want to get the best performance possible so I want to know *(if possible)* how can I start a game without a window manager. Maybe from TTY?

Comment: TTY doesn't provide a graphical interface layer - you still need the GUI.

Comment: This guide explains it how to do it with Kodi. So I guess this should be possible for a game. Alas don't get your hopes to much up. The little Ram you conserve won't change too much: http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux

Comment: You can, but you literally won't be able to manage windows -- creating new ones, closing existing ones, resizing, etc. A lightweight window manager like Openbox will make things **much** more convenient without any appreciable adverse effects on your games.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `startx` to start an xwindows server, then run the game.  This may not provide a good experience as some services may not have been started.

Choosing a lite-weight windows monitor such as is provide by the `lubuntu` or `xubuntu` installations may provide a better experience without a significant performance impact.  Disabling widgets may gain a little bit of performance.